# Parsing HTML and breaking lines in HTML text

Tags: java

I have plenty of Java code adding some HTML fragments on the server side. The HTML complexity can be variuous however it will have some text inside that must be broken according to specified line length.

So the argument is whole HTML frament:

```
<div class="container">
        <div id="header">
            <br class="cbt">
            <div id="hlogo">
                <a href="/" >
                    Stack Overflow
                </a>
```

I must for example break `Stack Overflow` to

```
Stack
Overflow
```

because it exceeded line length limit which would be 9 chars.

How could I do that? Meybe there is some library that would parse this HTML fragment to some document object and then I could break these lines, but what if the text is mixed with HTML ..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can parse your whole String with html content using [JSOUP Library](http://jsoup.org/). This library will transform all your **HTML Nodes** into **HTML Objects**, than you can iterate this objects looking for this texts with length > 9 breaking this inserting a 
 for example.

Example:

```
String html = "<html><head><title>First parse</title></head>"
  + "<body><p>Parsed HTML into a doc.</p></body></html>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
```

The **Documents** Object consist of Elements and TextNodes, the TextNode it is exactly what you looking for.

You can find some excelent examples in http://jsoup.org/cookbook/introduction/parsing-a-document

Hope it helps.